# Tensorflow pixel-wise comparison

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm building a CNN for a regression task in tensorflow.
I have a very special loss function which is sparse, because there are only a few pixelwise labels available for the predicted output image. In this loss function I want to divide two pixel values of the output image and compare the result with some given labels.
It would be easy to do it with for loops. However I need to do it in tensorflow operations to ensure that backpropagation is working (gradients have to calculated).

In more detail what I need and where I fail:

In this toy model I have 2 grayscale images of shape (batch, height, width):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# given:
# normalized greyscale image (batch=2):
grey_img = np.array([
                     # image 1:
                     [[ 0.65625   ,  0.67578125,  0.69140625],
                      [ 0.66796875,  0.6796875 ,  0.6953125 ],
                      [ 0.6796875 ,  0.69140625,  0.6796875 ]],
                     # image 2:
                     [[ 0.37890625,  0.3671875 ,  0.3671875 ],
                      [ 0.3828125 ,  0.37109375,  0.3671875 ],
                      [ 0.38671875,  0.37890625,  0.37109375]]
                    ])
grey_img_tf = tf.constant(grey_img)
```

I have a (sparse) list of pixel comparisons with labels.
I have for the comparison of point1 ('x1', 'y1') and point2 ('x2', 'y2') of batch ('batch') the label ('label' in {1, 2, 3}). ('x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2') represent the pixel indices of the greyscale image grey_img ('x1/2' is the on the width axis):

```
# labels are in order ['batch', 'x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'label']
labels = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1],
                   [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]])
```

What I need to do in a tensorflow-istic way is to compare the corresponding pixels in grey_img_tf:
eg for the first comparison I need to

```
# if point 2 is greater than point 1:
if grey_img[0, 1, 1] / grey_img[0, 0, 2] > 1:
    prediction = 1
# if point 1 is greater than point 2:
elif grey_img[0, 0, 2] / grey_img[0, 1, 1] > 1:
    prediction = 2
# if both are equal:
else:
    prediction = 3
```

I need to do this not for the np array but for the tensorflow grey_img_tf and over all batches.